# How to pass variable from Jenkins seed job to a job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have below seed job, which build another job, I am trying to pass the variable from seed job to actual job.

I am trying to pass COMMIT_SHA variable, however i am not successful
branches('${COMMIT_SHA}' is giving unknown propert error

```
configuration.k8sBuildJobsTest.keySet().eachWithIndex { service, index ->
pipelineJob("test-build-k8s-") {
    def jobIndex = "0${(index + 1).toString().padLeft(2, "0")}"
    def serviceName = "${configuration.resolveServiceName(service)}"
    displayName("${jobIndex} - Test Build ${serviceName}")
    logRotator {
        numToKeep(20)
        daysToKeep(30)
        artifactDaysToKeep(7)
        artifactNumToKeep(1)
    }
    parameters {
        stringParam("COMMIT_SHA", "", "[Required] Short SHA of the commit used to build the image")
   
    }
    
    definition {
        cpsScm {
        scriptText('''
            scm {
                git {
                    remote {
                        url("https://github.myrepo")
                        credentials("access-token")
                    }
                    branches('${COMMIT_SHA}')
                }
            }'''.stripIndent())
            scriptPath("cicd-azure/pipelines/test_build_k8s_service.jenkins")
            }
        }
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Where is the variable COMMIT_SHA defined? Is it a parameter of seed job?

Comment: It is defined in the above code


parameters {
        stringParam("COMMIT_SHA", "", "[Required] Short SHA of the commit used to build the image")
   
    }

Comment: You have defined a string parameter not a variable. If your seed job has parameters, you could bind and pass them to the job you are creating.